# How to pair line numbers making surfaces in a regular grid

Tags: python, list, algorithm, numpy, geometry

I have a bunch of points in 3D space that are connected by lines. I want to create 4-sided surfaces by detecting which lines can create such surfaces.

I have coordinates of my points, numbered lines, and also the point pairs which create lines. I uploaded a drawing to visualize it:

[image]

It shows point locations and their numbers in red colour, and lines and their numbers in blue. My points are distributed in a regular `x` and `y` grid, but are 3-dimensional.

Here is the corresponding data:

```
coordinates=np.array([[1.,1.,1.], [1.,2.,1.1], [1.,3.,0.9], [1.,4.,1.2],\
                      [2.,2.,1.2], [2.,3.,1.],[2.,4.,1.1],\
                      [3.,2.,1.1], [3.,3.,0.95],\
                      [4.,3.,1.], [4.,4.,1.05]])
y_lines=np.arange(17,24)
point_to_y_lines=[(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (5,6), (6,7), (8,9), (10,11)]
x_lines=np.arange(24,30)
point_to_x_lines=[(2,5), (3,6), (4,7), (5,8), (6,9), (9,10)]
```

Regarding my drawing: line numbers `18`, `25`, `20` and `24` create the first surface.

### The algorithm I am trying with

To find surfaces, I think comparing the center of lines is a logical way. I mean starting from line number `17`, I want to check the centers of which lines are closer than a limit to the center of this line (centers are shown by a black cross).

I select the limit based on the resolution in `x` coordinates, for example `1.3` looks fine. Only line number `24` is closer than the limit to the center of line `17`. So `17` cannot create any surfaces.

The next line is line number `18`, and centers of five lines are closer than the limit to it: `17`, `19`, `25`, `20` and `24`. `17` should be ignored because its value is less than 18 (first rule). `19` also should be ignored because it is only one number more than 18 and the `x` value of its center is the same as the center of line number `18` (second rule).

Then, the nearby centers to the center of line number `19` are `18` (will be removed because it is less than 19 (first rule)), `26`, `21` and `25`.

The next line is `20`, and the center of lots of lines are closer than the limit to it: `18` (first rule, removed), `25`, `24`, `21`, `28`, `22` and `27`. Line numbers `25` and `24` will be ignored because the `x` value of the their centers is less than the `x` value of the center of `20` (third rule), i.e. I go forward in `x` coordinates and do not include passed `x` coordinates.

Line number `21` will be removed because it is the only value more than 20 and its `x` is the same as line number `20` (second rule).

Next lines (`21`, `22` and `23`, I go until the last line of `y_lines`) cannot create any surface because of the mentioned rules.

### Desired output

The surfaces should be output as a list of tuples:

```
[(18, 25, 20, 24), (19, 26, 21, 25), (20, 28, 22, 27)]
```

I do appreciate any help for writing such an algorithm in python.

Comment: Are the surfaces to be found always tuples of 4? Or could it be 6, 8, ... depending on missing edges? Like for instance, if edges 20 and 25 would both not exist, would there be a surface?

Comment: Are lines always vertical or horizontal, and with size = 1? Or can there be lines that are longer, and possibly not vertical nor horizontal?

Comment: Dear @trincot, my surfaces are always made by four lines. Fortunately my cases are not that much choatic to have irregular shapes, they are always squares or rectangles. The size of grid in x and y can change and is not always 1, but in both directions it is fixed. For example size of verticals can be 1 and size of horizontals can be 1.5. My lines are also always vertical and horizontal.

Comment: There is also the z value. My fig shows a 2d view but z is also important but from one point to another one it is not changing a a lot. Thats why a limit like 1.3 looks safe for picking lines. A value like square root of resolution in x direction + resolution in y direction seems fine.

Comment: So because of the z-coordinate, the found surfaces will rarely be flat, i.e. the 4 points of a rectangle will not always lie in one plane, right?

Comment: Yeah, four points have not the same z value but they can make planar surface. I thought maybe the only way to find them is to use centers of lines.

Comment: I am thinking to another way, but I need to be sure about the z-coordinates: if they are such that the 4 points are not exactly on a single plane, does that exclude the square from the result? Or is that not a condition? In the example, I see that the first square (the only one I checked) has 4 points that are not exactly planar... its bent.

Comment: Aha, I see. With any shape, if they are close together and meet the condition I mentioned, they should be paired. In fact, I do not care about the shape of my planes and they can be tilted. The x and y coordinates are gentle but z makes the surfaces badly shaped.

Comment: OK, just to be sure: I am not concerned about tilted planes, but planes defined by 3 of the 4 points where the 4th point is not on that plane. Is that acceptable? If so, is there then still any other reason why the algorithm should look at the z-coordinate at all?

Comment: The point is that I do not want to create surfaces here. I just want to report the line numbers which create surfaces in another package. That package takes care of creating my surfaces but it needs line numbers.

Comment: Sure, I understand that you want tuples of line numbers. But that doesn't answer my question? Can the z-coordinate be ignored in identifying the squares or not? If not, on what ground should a square be rejected?

Comment: Aha, honestly I have no idea how you will deal with it but if it can do so without z, it will be perfect for me. I purposefully changed z a little bit in my data to show that I am working with flat surfaces. But if you method can do without z, definitely I have no problem and do appreciate your time, help and patience.

Comment: OK, one more thing, are the horizontal lines always linking points from less x to greater x? And the same question for the vertical lines. Or should the algorithm not assume that?

Comment: Yes, it is always increasing but I may have two grids one higher z values and another one in lower z values. Just considers two net of small surfaces on each other. In that case my points somewhere are restarted from the first coordinate toward the last. Just consider another layer of points bellow existing ones in my fig. They are increasing but i may have such breaks and restarts. I can also repeat your algorithm for the lower set ...

Comment: OK, I think I will post an answer now, not taking that multi layer aspect into account, although I think it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I do appreciate your help. Can I check it tomorrow and let you know any comments? I am in Germany and it is 12:13 AM and I have no access to my data and PC. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Of course, same time here in Belgium :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments show, there are a lot of things that need clarification, so my answer could still not be what you need.

I am making several assumptions about the problem:

- The z-coordinate is irrelevant for locating the squares
- There are only horizontal lines and vertical lines
- The horizontal lines are always having the point with the lesser x-coordinate in first place and the other, with a greater x-coordinate in second place. Similarly for the vertical lines...
- Lines do not intersect, except at their endpoints.
- The surfaces to be found always have 4 sides.
- A point has at the most 4 neighbors (in north, east, south, and west directions)

The problem is a graph problem, in which to find cycles of 4.

I propose to build an adjacency list, where each vertex has 4 neighbor references in clock-wise order (north, east, south, west), of which some can be `None`. When not `None`, the neighbor is described by a line number and the number of the connected vertex.

This algorithm does not really need to know about the coordinates, as already a lot of information is present in the data structure describing the lines.

Here is the code (I omitted numpy):

```
y_lines = list(range(17, 24))
point_to_y_lines=[(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (5,6), (6,7), (8,9), (10,11)]
x_lines = list(range(24,30))
point_to_x_lines=[(2,5), (3,6), (4,7), (5,8), (6,9), (9,10)]

from collections import defaultdict

# Create the empty adjacency list, prepared for lists of 4 entries per vertex
adj = defaultdict(lambda: [None]*4)

# Add vertical lines in the slots for north (0) and south (2)
for line, (a, b) in zip(y_lines, point_to_y_lines):
    adj[a][0] = (line, b)
    adj[b][2] = (line, a)  # also store the line in opposite direction

# Add horizontal lines in the slots for east (1) and west (3)
for line, (a, b) in zip(x_lines, point_to_x_lines):
    adj[a][1] = (line, b)
    adj[b][3] = (line, a)

# Main algorithm: find the rectangles
results = []
for corner in adj:  # for each vertex with at least one edge
    rect = []
    for direction in range(4):  # make a 90° turn at each next corner
        neighbor = adj[corner][direction]
        if not neighbor:  # Oops, no line in that direction. Give up.
            break
        line, corner = neighbor
        rect.append(line)
    else:  # We closed a rectangle
        results.append(tuple(rect))

print(results)
```